# Issues with directory Iterator and DB

Tags: php, database, iterator, directory

I have a folder that contains some images which is called

```
"20150205-job20513-Giraud"
```

and i want to create a php file that scan this folder and get all the necessary information from the images and put all that information in the Database ***"darwin_db"***.
So that what i did in the code bellow, Till know everything is good, but the probleme appears when i go inside the file from the localhost and no error appears but when i go to the database to verify if the data were written, i did not find anything in the corresponding table.

```
$path  = 'C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\Ketata Sodki\Todo\20150205-job20513-Giraud';
$dir   = new DirectoryIterator($path);
$files = array();
foreach ($dir as $key => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $dateCr = date("F d Y H:i:s.",$fileinfo->getCTime());
       $files[] = array(
            'id'            => $key,
            'filename'      => $fileinfo->getFilename(),
            'date-creation' => $dateCr,
            'extention'     => $fileinfo->getExtension(),
            'path'          => $fileinfo->getPathname(),
            'type'          => 'original'
        );
    }
}

//var_dump($files);

$db     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=darwin_db","root","");
foreach ($files as $data)
{$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO images (id, type, extension, path, filename, date_creation) 
                        VALUES (:id, :type, :extension, :path, :filename, :date_creation)");
$result->bindParam(':id', $data['id']);
$result->bindParam(':type', $data['type']); 
$result->bindParam(':extension', $data['extension']);
$result->bindParam(':path', $data['path']);
$result->bindParam(':filename', $data['filename']);
$result->bindParam(':date_creation', $data['date-creation']);
$etat   = $result->execute();
}
print $etat ;
```